# Function of x as input in function argument

Tags: r

I have written a function to approximate a derivate in a point x in R like this:

```
nderiv<- function(f,x,h){

    (f(x+h)-f(x))/h

}
```

And want to make an input in f as either x^2, "x^2" or as a predefined function like:

```
ex<- function(x){
         x^2
}
```

The code works fine if you use the last example (using a predefined function). But I can't get it to work when inserting the other options.

I either get the error

> Error in nderiv(x^2, 1) : object 'x' not found

or

> Error in nderiv("x^2", 1, 1e-04) : could not find function "f"

So I would like to be able to write `nderiv(x^2,1,0.0001)` or `nderiv("x^2",1,0.0001)` and get the value 2.0001.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the objective is to shorten the function specification then this works: library(gsubfn); fn$nderiv(~ x^2, 1, 0.0001)` .  See `?fn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `x^2` as an anonymous function, pass it to `nderiv` as `function(x){x^2}`. Something like:

```
nderiv(function(x){x^2}, 1, 0.0001)
```

Comment: Does that mean I have to write nderiv(function(x){x^2},1,0.0001)?

Comment: Yes, since you didn't supply a default value for `h`

Comment: There's no way I can write an if statement in the function to make the input "x^2" to a function? I tried writing nderiv(f,x,h){if(is.function){(f(x+h)-f(x))/h}else{function(x){f}(f(x+h)-f(x))/h}, but it didn't work for me. It interprets the string as character, and I don't know how to make it "non-character", so it actually functions as a function.

Comment: There is of course a way to pass a string which `nderiv` will convert to a function -- but why bother? The most natural way to write `nderiv` is as a function receiving a function, and `x^2` isn't a function. On the other hand, `function(x){x^2}` is.

Comment: The reason why is because it's for an assignment and the person looking at the code is not familiar with R. So i want it to be easy to make an input, and then I can do the hardwork in the code. The assignment is supposed to be in matlab, but we got an ok to write it in r if we wanted to. I've worked more in R and preffer doing it there :)

Comment: You could probably do something with `eval`

Comment: Thank you for you help john! I wrote: g<-function(x){eval(parse(text=f)) in an if/else statement, so if the input is a textstring, it transforms it to a function! :) Have a nice day, evening or night!